# Looking for a one word or phrase for making someone feel bad

Tags: single-word-requests

One word or phrase for making someone feel bad.

**Context**: during a normal conversation between two people an unintentional comment was made which made another person felt really bad like almost on the verge of crying. Other people have been criticized or been judgmental on that particular topic in past of which the speaker was completely unaware of.  That person wasn't expecting such comment from the speaker.

The speaker's insensitivity, made him/her felt _________ .

Comment: The common idiom is not one word. 'The speaker's insensitivity hurt their feelings' is by far the most common way of expressing this.

Comment: Another term is hard feelings. Something like "The speaker's insensitivity gave him/her hard feelings". Used to indicate the character harbors a grudge against the speaker.

Comment: If you were actually looking for a one word *or phrase* for making someone feel bad, why wouldn't "made him feel bad" work, please?

If you really want to satisfy the detail in the context, I suggest either there ain't no such animal or it would be "made him feel bad again".

Answer (score 2):

"Diminished" or "belittled" perhaps.

Comment: Answers are expected to be substantial, not brief, and supported by reference, not just opinion.

Comment: @NigelJ, we are not, however, providing a dictionary service and this is a single-word request which the gentleman has satisfied twofold quite nicely hasn't he?

Comment: Not at all, I am afraid.Take the tour again, @JesseIv, and particularly check the actual requirements for an answer on this site. My comment was made during my daily task of reviewing, which is one of the ways in which the quality of the EL&U site is maintained.